# How can I exclude several CSS files from precompilation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I hvae a Rails 3.2.x application that uses a 3rd party JS library which itself includes a few CSS files. When I precompile assets all of my JS goes into application.js and all the CSS into application.css.

I'd like for the CSS files, which I have put into vendor/assets/stylesheets to be excluded from precompilation but still available so the JS library can use them. Any suggestions on how I might do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Remove the following lines from application.css

in assets/stylesheets directory

```
  *= require_self
  *= require_tree .
```

These lines by default selects all the files in stylesheets directory for compilation..

Comment: then I could require the CSS files in my HTML using "/assets/<third party>.css" ?

Comment: That prevents the CSS from being included in pre-compilation. However, when I precompile assets for production, and then manually add a stylesheet tag to my layout to try and include the non-precompiled assets, I get an error: ActionView::Template::Error (epiceditor.css isn't precompiled)